# Import CSV into SQL Server database with bat or other script?

Tags: sql-server, csv, import

I am wondering if this is possible?

Does anyone know if it is possible to import a CSV file into an existing SQL Server database with existing tables? I am new to scripting and SQL Server I know a little bit but was wondering if anyone has an idea if this is even possible.

I have not tried anything yet cause I am not sure how or if this can be done ...

Comment: Its totally possible and there are loads and loads of resources out there explaining how... please do some research.

Comment: Dale I am more then willing to do that research any idea on what search terms to use and where I am all about learning Sir and thank you for your reply

Comment: Same search terms as your title. (No need to call anyone on this site sir).

Comment: I appreciate that, but it frequently implies a superiority - which is not good nor wanted, and regardless you should only address people as they wish to be addressed.

Comment: understood and will not happen again. Thank you for explaining I am new so I guess I have a lot to learn. I will try and do a search with my subject matter and see if I can find out how to do so I only asked my question here cause I really don't understand well enough to figure out the solution I am looking for.

Comment: Can't fully advise you when we don't know what your csv file contains, but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

To give you an edge:

INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
BULK 'C:\DATA\inv-2017-01-19.csv',
SINGLE_CLOB) AS DATA;

This works with existing table as append.
Please read the source found at Microsoft site:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

For one time imports more practical is to use the Import/Export Wizard to a receiver table after which you can let a batch append the data to your main table with the possibility of further filtering the source data.
Please read here:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-sql-server-management-studio/